# How to dynamically fill dropdown attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I need an attribute that is used in the Layered Navigation. The values for the dropdown attribute should be dynamically filled. An API service between Magento and an external ERP system provides product sync during the night. Values for the dropdown attribute could be added and should be somehow added to the available dropdown values.

It there anyway to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in my import, I use this function to add attribute option dynamically :

```
private function _addAttributeOption($idAttr, $label, $position = 0) {
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $optionTable = $setup->getTable('eav/attribute_option');
    $option['attribute_id'] = $idAttr;
    $cnx = $setup->getConnection();

    $data = array(
        'attribute_id' => $option['attribute_id'],
        'sort_order' => $position,
    );
    $cnx->insert($optionTable, $data);
    $option_id = $cnx->lastInsertId($optionTable);
    $option['value'] = array($option_id => array(0 => $label));
    $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
    return $option_id;
}
```